# Why is my conditional not working?using fgets output

Tags: c, input, file-io, newline, fgets

I need a method for getting each input characters and putting them in a 2D array (in this case a `char` array).

But as I need this from file input that has several end of lines (`\n`), I don't want these to be inserted into the array, so I was trying to make a conditional that if the character is a newline, it should not be placed in the array, but it doesn't seem to work.

Just to make clear, I am trying make this method by myself because I didn't find one online, and `fgets` was the best method I found.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char words[4][4][2];
    char verif[2];
  
    int i, j, l = 0, lin = 4, col = lin;

    printf("Insert numbers: ");
    for (i = 0; i < lin; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            fgets(verif, 2, stdin);
            //since I was using the IDE to write I also put a condition not to add the enter for the input but it doesn't work too lol

            if (strcmp(verif, "\n\0") != 0 || strcmp(verif, "\r\0") != 0)
            {
                printf("copying...\n");
                printf("%s\n", verif);
                strcpy(words[i][j], verif);
                l++;
            }
            else
                j--;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
        
    for (i = 0; i < lin; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf("-%s\t", words[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the input I would use to be placed in the matrix:

```
1234
1234
1234
1234
```

With a normal input like `1234123412341234` the output (printf matrix) is ok:

```
-1  -2  -3  -4  
-1  -2  -3  -4  
-1  -2  -3  -4  
-1  -2  -3  -4
```

Comment: Did you debug this? Why do you think that different input should result in the same output?

Comment: `strcmp` *compares* the *entire* string – you might want to search for the new line character only, so `strchr(verif, '\n')` – and you won't need to check for `\r` either, that character won't pass through the API anyway (`\r\n` is reduced to `\n` only unless you have opened a *file* in *binary* mode).

Comment: Using `fgetc()` and discarding the `'\n'` or `'\r'` characters would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @gettingAway – 
You confused `||` and `&&`.

Comment: Side note: String literals are null-terminated per se, and all the C-string API operates only up to the very first null character anyway. So the doubly terminated array you produce by `"\n\0"` won't be handled any differently than the singly terminated one `"\n"`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Idk if i understood your question correctly, but what i want to is actually put in a matrix, the output is just for a verification. The input on a txt file for example, would have 1234\n1234\n1234\n1234,and the"\n" would also be added in the array

Comment: @aconcagua right??? but it still doesn't work using strchr. I used strcmp because i read some post saying that "\r\0" would be the output for a "enter" using fgets.

Comment: @Armali May i know how lolll

Comment: @Fe203 For what i understood fgets saves the each input on buffer, then if i put 123 it would  get into the array. But if i discard the last input, the \r , the array would simply recieve null, isn't it?

Comment: Coming back on @Armali: `||` is wrong here! You compare your input against two values that are not equal – thus no matter how your input looks like it can only be equal to at most one of these – meaning it remains unequal to the other one – thus if not both, one of them is *always* true... You need to check if the string not equal to *any* of the two, thus unequal to *both* of them, thus you need `&&` (while second one is obsolete anyway)

Comment: Actually you are using `fgets` for reading just one single character – as limit 2 allows just such one while `fgets` null-terminates. You could compare simply the first character then: `*verif != '\n' && *verif != '\r'` – you can have it much simpler, as @Fe2O3 mentioned already, by always just reading single characters, such as [here](https://godbolt.org/z/feGafrPoq), skipping *any* whitespace – or do you intend to read longer strings later on?

Comment: @Aconcagua My purpose is only reading one character thought! Your statement worked just fine! Could you explain me the difference of it  from strchr(verif, '\n')==0, like aren't these the same characters? I didn't even think about using getchar ;-;  i feel i have wasted my life lolll. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @gettingAway – 
Excuse me, but how can I tell you how you came to think that you would have to use `||` where `&&` was in order? - Ah, I see Aconcagua explained it better.

Comment: Just checking the first character is an optimisation – the true error was using `||` instead of `&&`, which @Armali hinted to at the first place and which I tried to explain earlier, too. Given any arbitrary `a` and `b` with `a != b` then `c != a || c != b` is a tautology as `c` can ever be equal to just one of `a` or `b` and thus *must* be unequal to the other one (if it isn't to both anyway – which is what you actually are after and get by using `&&`!).

Comment: @Armali yeah i  didn't pay attention for that lol, i saw their answer now too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets(verif, 2, stdin)` is a contorted way to read a single byte from the standard input.  You could just write `int ch = getchar();` and handle the byte value directly instead of using string comparisons.

Yet the main problem lies in the test `if (strcmp(verif, "\n\0") != 0 || strcmp(verif, "\r\0") != 0)`: you should use `&&` instead of `||` as you want to handle input that is **neither** a newline **nor** a carriage return, which translates to (**not** a newline) **and** (**not** a carriage return).

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char matrix[4][4];
    int lin = 4, col = lin;

    printf("Enter the digits: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col;) {
            int c = getchar();
            if (c == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr, "premature end of file, aborting.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            if (c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
                printf("inserting %c\n", c);
                matrix[i][j] = c;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
        
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("-%c\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest using functions.
2. `strcmp` compares whole strings - you need to read a bit about them.
3. to compare 1 `char` you do not need to use string functions.
4. You can "manually" construct the string by null character terminating the array

```
int readWords(size_t size, char (*array)[size][2], FILE *fi)
{
    int result = 0;
    char buff[80] = "";
    size_t index = 0;
    
    for(size_t row =0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < size; col++)
        {
            if(buff[index] == 0 || buff[index] == '\r' || buff[index] == '\n')
            {
                if(!fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fi)) 
                {
                    result = -1;
                    goto cleanup_exit;
                }
                index = 0;
            }
            array[row][col][0] = buff[index++];
            array[row][col][1] = 0;
        }
    }
    cleanup_exit:
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char words[4][4][2];
    char verif[2];
  
    int i, j, l=0, lin=4, col=lin;

    printf("Insert numbers: ");
    if(!readWords(4, words, stdin))
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(i=0;i<lin;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            {
                printf("-%s\t", words[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error reading the array\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WsMqdedra